# iOS How to fetch rows from parse Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have one issues, i want to fetch from parse five row, when i print data wich i fetch it's workig normal, when i load data in variables, in my variables save only one row:

My code:

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "changeovers")
    query.addDescendingOrder("time_downtime1")
    query.limit = 5
    query.findObjectsInBackground { (objects, error) in
      for object in objects! {
        self. machineNameOne = object["stantionName"] as! String
        self. machineNameTwo = object["stantionName"] as! String
        self. machineNameThree = object["stantionName"] as! String
        self. machineNameFour = object["stantionName"] as! String
        self. machineNameFive = object["stantionName"] as! String
    }
}
```

[Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOyg4.png)

But i want for each variable will fetch each row.

**UPDATE:**

Code from answers:

[GIF CONSOLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmU06.gif)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'!' Don't use it in unwrapping. Obviously you will have single name that too last one in you for loop.

You should learn Codables to Parse JSON in Swift 4.

For now you should do something like this :

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "changeovers")
query.addDescendingOrder("time_downtime1")
query.limit = 5
var stationNames = [String]()
query.findObjectsInBackground { (objects, error) in
    if let objectArray = objects {
        for object in objectArray {
            if let stationName = object["stationName"] as? String {
                stationNames.append(stationName)

            } else {
                print("stationName is not present ")
            }
        }
        print("Station names : \(stationNames)")
    } else {
        print("objects is nil ")
    }
}
```

Comment: Closure expression is unused, Did you mean to use a 'do' statement?

Comment: In which line ?

Comment: gurad let stationName = object["stantionName"] as? String else {return}

Comment: @qunzi that was spelling mistake in guard. Can you check now.

Comment: Stil not working

Comment: What is the log's output ?

Comment: In print nothing. I make gif, you can see in question update

Comment: I have added print statements, can you tell the log output now ?

Comment: stationName is not present

Comment: @qunzi Updated the code with if let, can you tell the output now.

Comment: Thanks, it's working!